# splitting start and end date to start_date / first day of month and end_date / last day of month

Tags: sql, presto, gaps-and-islands, trino

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-02-21 | 2018-03-21 |
| 2018-03-21 | 2018-04-21 |
| 2018-04-21 | 2018-05-21 |
| 2018-05-21 | 2018-06-21 |

and I would like to turn it into:

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-02-21 | 2018-02-28 |
| 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-31 |
| 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 |
| 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-31 |
| 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-21 |

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issues are you facing?

Comment: Tried to apply some lead and lag functionality. dont know how to generate the last row

Comment: So update your question with the SQL you’ve written to generate everything except the last row and make it clear that you need help generating that row (hint: you may need to use UNION)

Comment: I got a solution, ranking the records and taking the last record as first in rank using union all. not sure it scalable but i'll try

Comment: You first need to collapse contiguous date intervals, then find all full-month intervals that fall between the resultant time frame and split the time frame accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this approach:

1. Collapse consequtive intervals into one. I prefer to use `match_recognize` for it.
2. Generate as much rows as there are months between start and end date of each interval: use `sequence` function in the correlated subquery.
3. For each row decide what is the start/end dates based on the interval.

Below is a query:

```
select
  grouped.id, /*Common key for group of rows*/
  grouped.grp, /*Sequence number for collapsed interval per ID*/
  cast(greatest(grouped.frame_from, mon.dt) as date) as date_start,
  least(grouped.frame_to, last_day_of_month(mon.dt)) as date_end
from t
match_recognize (
  partition by id /*Restart grouping at each ID*/
  order by start_date asc
  measures
    match_number() as grp,
    /*start_date of collapsed interval is the start_date of the first match*/
    first(start_date) as frame_from,
    /*end_date - end_date of the last match*/
    last(end_date) as frame_to
  /*Match group is any row followed by any number of consequtive intervals*/
  pattern (any_ conseq*)
  define
    /*Add row to a group if start_date is equal to end_date of the previous row*/
    conseq as start_date = prev(end_date)
) as grouped
  /*Generate rows for each grouped interval*/
  cross join unnest(sequence(
    cast(date_trunc('month', frame_from) as timestamp),
    cast(frame_to as timestamp),
    interval '1' month
  )) as mon(dt)
order by 1,2 asc,3 asc
```

which for this sample data

```
with t(id, start_date, end_date) as (
  values
  (1, date '2018-02-21', date '2018-03-21'),
  (1, date '2018-03-21', date '2018-04-21'),
  (1, date '2018-04-21', date '2018-05-21'),
  (1, date '2018-05-21', date '2018-06-21'),
  (1, date '2018-06-25', date '2018-08-23'),
  (2, date '2022-01-15', date '2022-02-15'),
  (2, date '2022-02-15', date '2022-03-15')
)
```

returns this result in AWS Athena 3 (which is based on Trino):

| # | id | grp | date_start | date_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2018-02-21 | 2018-02-28 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-31 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-31 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-21 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 2018-06-25 | 2018-06-30 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 2018-07-01 | 2018-07-31 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 2018-08-01 | 2018-08-23 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-31 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| 11 | 2 | 1 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-15 |